# Dummy Variable Trap & Cross-entropy in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I have a Tensorflow classifier using cross-entropy and one-hot truth labels in training. Is this susceptible to the dummy variable trap? If so should I remove one of the classes? If not then is `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` immune to the dummy variable trap? Code:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(truthLabels_placeholder)[0]
indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size), 1)
labels = tf.expand_dims(truthLabels_placeholder, 1)
concated = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[indices, labels])
onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated, tf.stack([batch_size,shared.nClasses]), 1.0, 0.0)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=onehot_labels)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not susceptible to the dummy variable trap. These notes motivate creating a loss function for classification using the cross-entropy and softmax functions: http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax.